# How to properly register a click event on a radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically creating HTML radio buttons where I am assigning the Id of the input tag to a variable. I want to append a click event handler to these radio buttons using the Id I have assigned. How do I properly use the Id I created to generate a click event? Right now, the event is not being triggered at all.

```
generateDynamicHTML(function (structure) {
let keys = Object.keys(structure);
keys.forEach(function(key){
    let radioButton = $("<input type='radio' name='studentName' id=" + key + "/><label for=" + key + ">" + key + "</label>");
    radioButton.appendTo('#studentToggle')

    $("#" + key).click(function () {
        console.log(key);
    })
})
```

})

I am using the console.log to test if the method was being hit but I am getting empty results. I know the keys are correct because the radio buttons are being created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I usually just place one click handler onto one of the parent elements that won't change. Then you can use event.target to detect if an input was clicked. That way you can add as many options as you want, without having to add an event handler to each individual one. Also, since it's a radio button, you might want 'change' instead of 'click'. Something like `$(parentContainer).on( 'change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use event delegation, you never have to add extra event handlers to options as long as their parent does not change:

```js
const generateDynamicHTML = function( structure ) {
  return Object
    .keys( structure )
    .map(function( key ) {
      return '<input type="radio" name="studentName" id="' + key + '"/><label for="' + key + '">' + key + '</label>';
    })
    .join( '' );
};
    
const fields = $( '#student_fields' );
//  Add the click handler before any radios
fields.on( 'click', 'input[type="radio"]', function( event ) {
  console.log( event.target.id );
});
//  Add the radios, the click stil works
fields.append( generateDynamicHTML({
  "john": { "age": 21 },
  "jane": { "age": 20 }
}));
//  Add more radios
fields.append( generateDynamicHTML({
  "dave": { "age": 21 },
  "joe": { "age": 19 }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="student_fields">
  <legend>Students</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I would like, thank you. Instead of printing the target, is there a way to retrieve the values of the selected key? I apologize for deviating from the initial question.

Comment: Ofcourse. The event.target is just the radio button that got clicked. So you can get any value or attribute from it. Or wrap it in $( event.target ) and continue from there as if you selected it on id. Think you might even be able to use `this` to refer to the radio. The problem is that the value of clicking a radio is always 'on', so it does not tell me much if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the id added is `key/` not `key`. You should leave a space between `"` and the closing of the input tag. Or use template literals.

See below

```js
const structure = {
  'first': 1,
  'second': 2
}

let keys = Object.keys(structure);
keys.forEach(function(key) {
  let radioButton = $("<input type='radio' name='studentName' id=" + key + " /><label for=" + key + ">" + key + "</label>");
  
  // or template literals
  // let radioButton = $(`<input type='radio' name='studentName' id=${key} /><label for=${key}>${key}</label>`);
 
  radioButton.appendTo('#studentToggle')
  $("#" + key).click(function() {
    console.log(key);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="studentToggle">

</div>
```

Comment: Would be smart to quote the attribute value

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems that the click event is not being fired still, using the template literal.

Comment: well..when you click on the element, the id appears in console. isn't that what you want ?